# jQuery Mobile - Resize image before uploading

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

I'm working in a jQuery Mobile app that the user can take pictures (with iPhone) and upload it online.

But the iPhone image is big, very big, something like 2448x3264 on pixels size and 3mb file size.

Is there any way to reduce this image locally on the phone and when the user click the upload button the image is uploaded with the reduced size? Like 640x480 and less than 3mb?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are after using this canvas resize javascript library:

https://github.com/gokercebeci/canvasResize

It resizes the image in the browser and then uses ajax to send the resized image information. There is a full example provided - check the index.html file on git page, as well as an example php file for receiving the uploaded image information.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but unfortunately there's a bug with jQuery Mobile 1.4, does not work. Still no luck :(.

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Are you using zepto or jquery - I don't think jquery mobile is compatible with zepto. Also check what version of jquery you are using.

Comment: No error message at all, the page simply does not open, I mean, it slides (using jQuery Mobile 1.4.2) to open and stays blank. I'm using jQuery 1.8.2 only no Zepto. I think it's related to 'binaryajax.js', if I remove it the page opens, but the canvasResize only works with it.

Answer (score -1):

There is an app for iPhone called **Simple Resize** that gives you choices to resize photo. You can use the app to take the photo or use one from camera roll.